# Permanently overriding application.properties programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I would like to develop an API which enables a non-programmer to set e-mail properties like the port or a the host. I discovered that I can load properties in a class using the Spring Boot annotation @ConfigurationProperties.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company.mail")
@Data
public class ConfigProperties {

    private Long port;
    private String host;

}
```

I can retrieve the properties using e.g. getPort and set them using setPort.

However, using this method the actual values in the application.properties file don´t change when I use setPort or setHost. Consequently the changes get lost when I restart the application. Is there a way to actually change the values in the application.properties file or do I need a database from where I can load the properties when the application starts?

Comment: You may use external config file. 

check spring documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Additionally you may use the following useful tutorial on externalizing your config file on git. https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/spring-boot-external-configuration-with-spring-cloud-config-and-spring-actuator-60603f2ff23f

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize your config files (check spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)).

In order to do so add the following dependency in your pom.xml:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then on your git server create a git repository and add the following into your application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=http://{yourGitRepoUrl}.git
```

And add @EnableConfigServer annotation to your SpringBootApplication  class.
and finally link your app to your config server by adding the following to application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8080  #whatever your port is
```

For more detail check this nice [Tutorial](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/spring-boot-external-configuration-with-spring-cloud-config-and-spring-actuator-60603f2ff23f).